# What's the difference between HEAD and HEAD~1?

Tags: git

It was suggested to me that I could restore my code to the way it is in the origin repository using this command:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

I looked for information on this but didn't find anything that explained

```
HEAD~1
```

What does the ~1 part of the command do?

Comment: Might be useful: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Comment: I don't feel like the "possible duplicate" fully answers this question - yes, it does explain what `~1` is, but the suggested command in the question is also likely not the right choice, so I feel that the question deserves being covered in more detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+HEAD+tilde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation for this syntax is in the `gitrevisions` manpage.

`HEAD~1` means: go back 1 commit from `HEAD`, using the first parent (most commits have only one parent, so this syntax covers most cases where you want to go further back).

`HEAD~1` is so common that it can also be shortened to `HEAD~`.

It's important to understand, though, that `HEAD` has little to do with the state of the origin repository! `HEAD~1` will happen to match the current state of the origin in these cases:

- You just pulled (merged) from the origin, and it created a merge commit (prompted for a merge commit message).
- You were up-to-date with the origin and then made a single new commit on top.

In other cases you would probably use `@{upstream}` which references the upstream of your current branch (also documented in the `gitrevisions` manpage).

Finally, `--soft` often isn't the right choice, either. It means that all your changes will be preserved in the working tree and index. Your files won't change at all, and `git status` will show all the changes as "to be committed".

If you want to basically hit the reset button and **irrevocably destroy** all committed and uncommitted changes you have locally compared to the upstream, I recommend this:

```
git reset --hard @{upstream}
```